# Check if user +1ed the URL

Tags: javascript

I'd like to check if a visitor has +1ed a certain URL (and show him a +1 button if he hasn't).  Any ideas?

Comment: If you use the correct code for a +1 button, it will be highlighted blue if they have already clicked it, giving them the opportunity to un+1 it, if they wish.  This is common functionality all over the web, so it would be best to stick with it for user familiarity.  Does that resolve the issue, or is there a reason you want to know if they've +1'd it?  See here... http://www.google.com/intl/en/webmasters/+1/button/index.html

Answer (score 1):

There's a *hidden* API for the counts, available at the following URL:

> https://clients6.google.com/rpc?key=AIzaSyCKSbrvQasunBoV16zDH9R33D88CeLr9gQ

It expects POST data in JSON-RPC format, so you'll need to send a request like this:

```
[{
    "method": "pos.plusones.get",
    "id": "p",
    "params": {
        "nolog": true,
        "id": "http://www.mydomain.com/mypage",
        "source": "widget",
        "userId": "@viewer",
        "groupId": "@self"
    },
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "key": "p",
    "apiVersion": "v1"
}]
```

However, you won't be able to use this in JavaScript due to the Same-Origin policy.  This means you'll have to set up a server-side solution unless you go for Option 2.

Option 2 is what I use on a couple custom social plugins.  A very simple API is available at http://sharedcount.com, which offers the result as JSON-P if a callback is specified:

```
var scr = document.createElement("script");
    myUrl = encodeURIComponent("http://mydomain.com/mypage"),
    apiUrl = "http://api.sharedcount.com/?url="+myUrl+"&callback=shareCounts";

scr.src = apiUrl;
document.body.appendChild(scr);

function shareCounts(data) {
    alert(data.GooglePlusOne);
}
```

Comment: Andy,
https://clients6.google.com/rpc?key=AIzaSyCKSbrvQasunBoV16zDH9R33D88CeLr9gQ displays a short JSON:

`{"error":{"code":500,"message":"Unknown Error","data":[{"domain":"global","reason":"internalError","message":"Unknown Error"}]}}`

Comment: @muszek: that's right, as I said you need to post the JSON data in the format I mentioned.  THen you get a response that looks like `[
 {
  "result": {
   "kind": "pos#plusones",
   "id": "http://www.mydomain.com/mypage",
   "isSetByViewer": false,
   "metadata": {
    "type": "URL",
    "globalCounts": {
     "count": 0.0
    }
   },
   "abtk": "AEIZW7TFKLazpoaBz5KSYd9ItQyTLU7RbNGZBQQ/4b0MksJc4nk1VQzi/9gOnW54uC0ayeGIukD/mf0oTILvm3YykHGsMTdIzlodEiIbSZCy0n9IwGkgwoo="
  },
  "id": "p"
 }
]`
 – I just tested this myself using Fiddler.